# Using specifically vs specific

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure

Please critique my sentences below.

1. This code is specifically for this type of production.
2. This code is specific for this type of production.

I feel like option 2 is correct. Please provide some feedback on when to use each word.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1, *specifically*, sounds more natural to this US English speaker.

**Specifically** is an adverb, so it modifies verbs.
**Specific** is an adjective, so it modifies nouns.

One of the definitions of *specifically* includes

> —used to indicate the exact identity, purpose, or use of something
> *The show is aimed specifically at a female audience.*

and "used to indicate the purpose or use of something" is exactly what we want to do in this sentence; the code is *intended* for this type of production.

It is not impossible or wrong to say "specific for this", but it means something more like "unique to this thing."  For example,

> [...a patient visiting a hospital can have several identifiers associated with him or her — a number that uniquely identifies that person across all hospital visits, and an account number that is **specific for this** particular visit.](https://www.google.com/books/edition/XQuery_Kick_Start/5clQOZKw_O8C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22is%20specific%20for%20this%22&pg=PP28&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22is%20specific%20for%20this%22)